# Date picker Change in vb.net

Tags: datepicker

I am using **datetime picker** in **vb.net**. When I change the time the date also changes. I want that when I change the time the date does not change.

Comment: How are you changing the time?  From the front end or code?  How are you initialising it?

Comment: do you want time format

Comment: I meant are you setting the time in code or from the user interface?

Comment: yes . i am set custom date and time in code part

Comment: Please post your code.  It is impossible to assist without seeing your code to identify where things are going wrong for you.

Comment: I want calender picker dll. Do you anything .Code project calender dosen't work

Comment: i want to  disable the pop in date time picker

Comment: i am check out .It working correctly.

Comment: do you know any dll for calender

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378900/Calendar-NET .